# vb syntax in CAD iLogic program

Tags: vb.net, cad, autodesk

I have the following line of code in iLogic which is based on vb (I think):

```
ActiveSheet.View("VIEW1").ScaleString = "1'=1'-0" & Chr(34)
```

which basically sets the view scale based on a string to 1' = 1'-0" (or true scale).

This one works no problem, but since I gathered this from Autodesk's help forum on a similar topic, so I am not sure of the syntax entirely, but I want to set the view scale to 1" = 1'-0".

I have tried the following, but I am getting an error.

```
ActiveSheet.View("VIEW1").ScaleString = "1 & Chr(34) & =1'-0" & Chr(34)
```

I know this has got to be a simple fix, but can some one please give me some generic vb advice?

Answer (score 1):

& Chr(34) & will currently appear inside this string. Try:

```
ActiveSheet.View("VIEW1").ScaleString = "1" & Chr(34) & "=1'-0" & Chr(34)
```